# Python connector error on trying to delete using user input

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error, mysql-connector

I have implemented most other basic database transactions including insert,update,select with similar syntax,but on trying to delete,i get error

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

What would the correct syntax be? I must delete according to user input. Here is a shortened version of my code,minus the insert,select,update part.:

```
elif (choice == 4):
    mail=raw_input('Enter email of user to be deleted:')
    print 'Deleting..'
    delete_user_details(mail)


def delete_user_details(email):

    sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE email = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql,email)
```

Comment: Is that all of your code?  The sql line isn't at line 1

Comment: Knowing error is on the first line, maybe your connection string has some problems? You should post more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass query parameters to [`cursor.execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) as a *tuple*, even for a single parameter. Try this:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE email = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (email,))
```

Comment: Ah!! Thanks a lot!! I don't know how i missed that in the documentation.

Comment: Silly syntax error like missing the comma in the tuple was giving me a headache. Always a joy to see the right code and notice the mistake in mine! Thanks