# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

i am writing code that reads from one deletes a record my a mysql table but everytime i run it comes up with the error:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

this is my code:

```
ID3 = 3
query4 = ("""DELETE FROM users WHERE userID = %s""")
recordTuple4 = (ID3)
cursor.execute(query4,recordTuple4)
```

Comment: `recordTupkle4` needs to be a `tuple`, and what makes a `tuple` a `tuple` is the comma, not the parentheses.  Try `recordTuple4 = (ID3,)`

Comment: worked great cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python connector error on trying to delete using user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054381/python-connector-error-on-trying-to-delete-using-user-input)